# Responsive File Manager. Prevent modal close on image select

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-manager

The plugin is this: http://www.responsivefilemanager.com

I'm using the stand-alone feature in a bootstrap modal. Is it possible to prevent modal close on image select?

Answer (score 2):

Responsive File Manager not support using the stand-alone feature in a bootstrap modal.

You can use javascipt popup instead of bootstrap modal.

```
<a href="javascript:open_popup('filemanager/dialog.php?type=1&popup=1&amp;field_id=logo')" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Image</a>
```

Do not forget add popup parameter and value (1) to URL dialog.php?type=1&**popup=1**&field_id

And popup open_popup method for JS.

```
function open_popup(url)
{
    var w = 880;
    var h = 570;
    var l = Math.floor((screen.width - w) / 2);
    var t = Math.floor((screen.height - h) / 2);
    var win = window.open(url, 'ResponsiveFilemanager', "scrollbars=1,width=" + w + ",height=" + h + ",top=" + t + ",left=" + l);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First off this is a plugin so not garenteed to work with framework such as bootstrap.
Ideally would need to see your code to make a judgement on the problem.

A modal will close on "submit" as the modal is designed as a pop-up, you click something then it goes, you can place form elements in the modal, but soon as "submit" button is clicked, the modal closes. I would suggest looking at the coding (as i cant) and see if the image select function is casuing it to close.

Again place your code in a fiddle and we can all look at it better.